# How to send a file to the user via MVC, which is still being copied?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, storage, sharing

How to send a file to the user via MVC, which is still being copied?
I need find some way to allow application to send first data copied so that the user can download whole file to be copied, in case that copying is faster of course.

I have project which will be used as web storage, on each server is 2 discs, first of them is like cache (ssd) second is for storage, when user wants to download file, file from storage is copied from second to first and after that is file provided to user.

For files in GB sizes it is not really fast solution, any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not send it directly from disc 2? And only copy additionally copy it to disc 1 when it's accessed multiple times.

Comment: Can't you do a simultaneous copy? One providing it to the user (as @user3038092 suggests) and one copying it to the cache? Can you read this file simultaneously (via a `FileStream` for instance)?